# No access to properties when inserting to child tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47AUs.png)

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void AddEmployementRequest(EmployementRequest emp)
    {   
        EmployeeSkill employeeSkill = new EmployeeSkill
        {
            Skill = emp.,
            Description = emp.
        };
        EmployeeLanguage employeeLanguage = new EmployeeLanguage
        {
            Name = emp.,
            ConversationLevel = emp.
        };
        EmployeeCours employeeCours = new EmployeeCours
        {
            Date =emp. ,
            Course = emp.,
            Duration = emp.,
            Association = emp.,
            Description = emp.
        };
        EmployementRequest employementRequest = new EmployementRequest
        {
            Name = emp.Name,
            Address = emp.Address,
            Surnam = emp.Surnam,
            Father = emp.Father,
            IDNumber = emp.IDNumber,
            IDCardNumber = emp.IDNumber,
            IDCity = emp.IDCity,
            Birthday = emp.Birthday,
            Birthplace = emp.Birthplace,
            Nationality = emp.Nationality,
            Religion = emp.Religion,
            Phone = emp.Phone,
            Cell = emp.Cell,
            EmergencyAddress = emp.EmergencyAddress,
            EmergencyName = emp.EmergencyName,
            EmergencyPhone = emp.EmergencyPhone,
            ParentedPeople = emp.ParentedPeople,
            Gender = emp.Gender,
            MarriageStatus = emp.MarriageStatus,
            Residency = emp.Residency,
            InsuranceCode = emp.InsuranceCode,
            InsuranceStatus = emp.InsuranceStatus,
            VehicleType = emp.VehicleType,
            MilitaryServiceStatus = emp.MilitaryServiceStatus,
            EducatedFrom = emp.EducatedFrom,
            EducationField = emp.EducationField,
            EducationGrade = emp.EducationGrade,
            ExtraWorkCapability = emp.ExtraWorkCapability,
            LeisureTimeHobbies = emp.LeisureTimeHobbies,
            Salary = emp.Salary,
            IntroducerName = emp.IntroducerName,
            IntroductionMethod = emp.IntroductionMethod,
            Illness = emp.Illness,
            VehicleStatus = emp.VehicleStatus,
            PKEmploymentRequest = Guid.NewGuid(),
        };
        employementRequest.EmployeeLanguages.Add(employeeLanguage);
        employementRequest.EmployeeSkills.Add(employeeSkill);
        employementRequest.EmployeeCourses.Add(employeeCours);
        using (var db = new UKN_DBNAMEEntities())
        {
            db.EmployementRequests.Add(employementRequest);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I want to insert to all parent and child tables at once ,As you can see I can't access the properties in child tables and also there's no intellisense to show the properties unlike the parent

I think I need a Linq query but I have no idea

Comment: mmm... In your object EmployementRequest (what you get from the function) I think it's full with all parameters so why not do only 
`using (var db = new UKN_DBNAMEEntities())
        {
            db.EmployementRequests.Add(emp);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
[WebMethod]
public void AddEmployementRequest(EmployementRequest emp) {           
    emp.PKEmploymentRequest = Guid.NewGuid();
    using (var db = new UKN_DBNAMEEntities()) {
        db.EmployementRequests.Add(emp);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

It may/should do, but...

Consider:

- using [automapper](http://automapper.org/) or the like;
- use some query to avoid recreation of Language or Skil